# How to automate authentication flow for Firebase with Google Provider using REST API?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have a system that is using `Firebase` authentication with `Google` provider. I have an issue with automating integration tests for API. Tests are represented by a bunch of HTTP requests (Postman collections). I need to do some steps before tests to get a token from Firebase.

Only solution I can see is to add `refresh token` to the tests and call Refresh token endpoint to get a new token. Not sure how long will the refresh token live. Doesn't look like a good solution. E2E frameworks like Selenium are not an option.

What I want to achieve in the ideal scenario:
The input for the test is username/password for Google account and maybe settings pointing to the correct Firebase project. I need to perform some 
magic HTTP requests (without user interaction) to get Firebase token back.

Does anyone knows if that is feasible? If not - how this flows can be automated without Selenium?